# MySQL DISTINCT by one column

Tags: mysql

How can I get the DISTINCT function looking at only one column?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id AS uniqueid,
    ProductCode AS ProductID,
    DisplayName AS ReportingLabel,
    REPLACE(URL, 'http', 'https') AS URL,
    ProductCategory AS Category,
    Description,
    CONCAT('https://', ImageURL) AS Image,
    latestSellingPrice AS Price,
    Brand,
    IF(latestSellingPrice > 300,
        'TRUE',
        'FALSE') AS Is_Default,
    IF(StockAvailable > 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS InStock
FROM
    XML_Import_Server
WHERE
    Brand = 'Totalsports' 
AND 
    DisplayName <> 'eGift Card'
```

The ProductCode's aren't always unique because of size and colour options. But I only need to pull the first variant of it.

Comment: No. `DISTINCT` is the short form. The complete form is `DISTINCT ROW`. If it uses only one column, what row to pick when there are two or more rows that have the same value on that column and different values on the other columns?

Comment: i think you need to use `GROUP BY` here to do what you want. you could use `DISTINCT` but grouping correctly the rows that matter you is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use aggregatio function   and group by 
eg for some columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id AS uniqueid,
  min(ProductCode) AS ProductID,
  DisplayName AS ReportingLabel

FROM
    XML_Import_Server
WHERE
    Brand = 'Totalsports' 
AND 
    DisplayName <> 'eGift Card'    
group by id, DisplayName
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by *first variant*.  So I will guess that you mean the variant with the lowest `id` value.

Do this with a subquery joined to your main table.  The subquery finds the `id` values that are relevant.

```
                    SELECT MIN(id) id
                      FROM XML_Import_Server
                     GROUP BY ProductCode
```

Try this to convince yourself it gives you the right choice for each different `ProductCode` value.

Then, join that to your main query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id AS uniqueid,
    a.whatever,
    a.whatever
FROM
    XML_Import_Server a
JOIN (
                        SELECT MIN(id) id
                          FROM XML_Import_Server
                         GROUP BY ProductCode

     ) b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
    a.whatever = whatever
```